# Field Key under Sitecore Forms Conditional Setting not updating on duplicating

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have form section on which some conditions are applied. when i am duplicating section to create new one then Field Key under Sitecore Forms Conditional Setting not updating due to which conditions are not working.
How to fix this ?

Comment: I believe the only option is to create a Sitecore Support ticket

Comment: Could you please add more details with the steps to create this?  Sitecore Support would be the most perfect team to answer this quickly.

Comment: @NikhilKulkarni Steps to create :
Create Section in form.
Duplicate the section.
After duplicate both section will have same "Field Key" under Condition Settings Section.

As Field Key is not getting updated on Duplicate due to which Form Conditions are not working.